# Computing Parallel Lines Between Vectors

Tags: vectors

Compute the distance between the parallel lines given by $(1, 4) + t\cdot (4, 3)$ 
and $(-5, 6) + s\cdot (4, 3)$.

I tried drawing out these lines and dropping an altitude but I'm not sure how to go on from here.

Answer (score 0):

The first line can be written as $3x-4y+13=0$, and the second line can be written as $3x-4y+39=0$. Hence the distance between the two lines is $$\frac{39-13}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}} = \frac{26}{5}$$

Note: For two parallel lines $L_1=ax+by+c_1=0$ and $L_2=ax+by+c_2=0$, the distance is given by $$d(L_1,L_2)=\frac{|c_1-c_2|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to remember how to compute the perpendicular distance of a line from the origin, you can simply find the difference between the two distances. However, your idea of dropping a perpendicular is workable, too: find the intersection of any perpendicular line with these two and the distance between those points is also the distance between the two lines.

The direction vector of the two lines is $(4,3)$, so perpendicular lines to these will have direction $(-3,4)$ with equation $4x+3y=C$. Taking a line through the origin ($C=0$) is the simplest choice. Plugging in the coordinates of the two given lines gives the equations $$4(4t+1)+3(3t+4)=0 \\ 4(4s-5)+3(3s+6)=0.$$ Solve these equations for $s$ and $t$, substitute back into the parameterizations of the two lines and then compute the distance between the two resulting points.